# jquery get select option siblings

Tags: jquery, arrays, html-select

I'm trying to get all options other than the selected one and with the different class than the selected one.

Consider the following example:

```
<select name="country" id="country">

    <option value="1" class="option_vat" selected="selected">United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="2" class="option_no_vat">United States</option>
    <option value="3" class="option_vat">Spain</option>
    <option value="4" class="option_vat">Portugal</option>

</select>
```

Now when change() event is called I want to get the class of the selected option and classes of other options, which are different to the selected one.
In this case the only class that would be added to array would be 'option_no_vat' as Spain and Portugal option have the same class at the selected one (United Kingdom).

Could someone suggest a solution please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var classes;

$('#country').change(function()
{
    classes = [];

    $(this).find('option:not(:selected)')
        .not('.' + $(this).find(':selected').attr('class'))
        .each(function()
        {
            var class = $(this).attr('class');

            if ( $.inArray( class, classes ) == -1 )
                classes.push(class);
        });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9JEyY/

**Note:** This'll only work correctly if you have just one class per element.

Comment: @user398341: If you're using Firefox, then yes. Other browsers have their own console...

Comment: Thanks for that Joseph - works great - I've also added check for existence of the class as well in the if () statement to make sure that it has class assigned.

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/vKXMP/1/

```
$("select#country").change(function(){
    var $that, cls;
    $that = $(this);
    cls = $that.find("option:selected").attr("class"); //returns the class of the selected elements... only works when there is only one class
    console.log( $that.find("option").not("."+cls) ) //gives you back a jquery object of all the elements with a different class then the one selected
});
```

next time, at least try something.

Comment: +1. Another way of getting the selected element would be `this.options[this.selectedIndex]`.

Comment: @Felix Kling. oh boy i forget about my JS basics all the time... thank you

Comment: @user398341 maybe you should open your ey.. ehm console :)

Comment: Well, it is easy to forget these things when using jQuery... I think you are not alone, no worries :)

Comment: Is this going to get me array of classes other than the selected one - or all options regardless whether they have a class assigned or not?

Comment: @user398341 i don't know how i could make it clearer, check the example and tell me if it was you need or not. As the comment in the code example i have posted suggests: it gives you back a jQuery *Object* containing the OTHER select elements that don't have the same class then the selected.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wy5Sp/)**

```
$(function(){
    $("#country").change(function(){
        var classes = [], class;
        var currentClass = $(this).find("option:selected").attr('class');
        $(this).find("option").each(function(){
            class = $(this).attr('class');
            if(class != currentClass){
                if($.inArray(class, classes) == -1){
                    classes.push(class);
                }
            }
        }); 
        alert(classes.join(","));
    }).change();
});
```

`classes` array will contain all the unique classes which you need.